# Hubspot bulk add property

Tags: php, hubspot

I want to add multiple emails at once through Hubspot API. I used a foreach loop to add emails but, after 30 seconds, it is showing execution time is exceeded. Is there a bulk way to add a property through Hubspot API?

```
foreach ($leads as $lead) {
  $data['email'] = $lead['email'];
  $data['firstname'] = $lead['name'];
  $hubspot = new HubSpot($autoDetails[3]->api_creds_required);
  $hubspot->contacts()->create_contact($data);
  $email = $hubspot->contacts()->get_contact_by_email($lead['email']);
  $result = $hubspot->lists()->add_contacts_to_list($email->vid, $autoDetails[0]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Please edit your post with your code so we can more easily and faster, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As recommended in [Hubspot's docs](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/faq/working-within-the-hubspot-api-rate-limits), you'll want to use their [Batch API](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/contacts/batch_create_or_update), which allows you to create or update up to 100 contacts in one request.

You might also want to check out this open source [PHP Hubspot wrapper](https://github.com/ryanwinchester/hubspot-php), which supports this same endpoint.